# How to drop table when a colum was setted cascade

Tags: mysql, mariadb, cascade

I have an issue with Mariadb query. I have two tables like below

```
 CREATE TABLE kayttaja (
      kayttaja_id integer NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
      kayttaja_tunnus varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      kayttaja_salasana_encrypted varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      kayttaja_enabled tinyint NOT NULL,
      kayttaja_suku varchar(255) default NULL,
      kayttaja_etu varchar(255) default NULL,
      CONSTRAINT fk_rooli_id FOREIGN KEY(fk_rooli_id) REFERENCES rooli(rooli_id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE kayttaja_rooli (
  id integer NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  fk_kayttaja_id integer NOT NULL,
  fk_rooli_id integer NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (fk_kayttaja_id) REFERENCES kayttaja(kayttaja_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY (fk_rooli_id) REFERENCES rooli(rooli_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now i want to drop kayttaja table, how can i do? I've already drop kayttaja_rooli table, thanks.

Comment: What was the error you received ?

Comment: check that column/key exists

Comment: I use the query to drop foreign key first: 

alter table kayttaja drop foreign key fk_kayttaja_id but it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop it normally using

```
drop table if exists kayttaja;
```

If you have problems with foreign key youcan disable them ,drop the table and enable them again

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
drop table if exists kayttaja;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```